# Pop content from pushed Stack object into textarea

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, stack

I'm looking to take an object that contains String and Integer context and that has pushed upon a Stack and pop those specific contents into a display that the user can see.  The display consists of two textareas and a label.

I can't figure out how to access the individual parts of the Object to display them though..

Here's my Stack.as class:

**Stack.as**

```
package
{

// credit for this class: *@author Michael Avila

import Node;

public class Stack
{
    private var first:Node;

        public function isEmpty()
        {
            return first == null;
        }

        public function push(data:Object)
        {
            var oldFirst : Node = first;
            first = new Node ();
            first.data = data;
            trace(first.data.toString());
            first.next = oldFirst;
        }

        public function pop():Object 
        {
            if (isEmpty())
            {
                trace ("Error: \n\t Objects of type Stack must contain data before you attempt to pop");
                return true;
            }
            var data = first.data;
            return Object;
    }
  }
}
```

And here's how i'm popping it:

...

```
private function nextMoveLPart(event:EffectEvent):void  // open up connection get 
        {
            if(shuffle == 0)
            {
            var r:Object = s.pop();
            trace(r);
            stext1.text = r.cSide1;
            trace(r.cSide1);
            stext2.text = r.cSide2;
            cardNumberLabel.text = r.id;
```

...

Here's how I'm pushing it on stack:

```
if(i<=numResults-1)
            {

                var row:Object = result.data[i];
                s.push(row);
                stext1.text = row.cSide1;
                stext2.text = row.cSide2;
                cardNumberLabel.text = row.id;
            }
```

Any help or advice would be awesome and much appreciated.  Thank you!

**REVISION**

To Push:

```
public var stackArray:Array = new Array();
```

...

```
if(i<=numResults-1)
            {

                var row:Object = result.data[i];
                stackArray.push(row);
                stext1.text = row.cSide1;
                stext2.text = row.cSide2;
                cardNumberLabel.text = row.id;
            }
```

To Pop:

```
if(shuffle == 0)
            {

                var r:Object = stackArray.pop();
                if(r != null)
                {
                stext1.text = r.cSide1;
                stext2.text = r.cSide2;
                cardNumberLabel.text = r.id;
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this part is wrong

```
public function pop():Object 
        {
            if (isEmpty())
            {
                trace ("Error: \n\t Objects of type Stack must contain data before you attempt to pop");
                return true;
            }
            var data = first.data;
            return Object; <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<why just return Object, why not return first.data and remove first.data from the list.
    }
```

Looks like a linked list implementation if an array could be used it'll probably save some headaches by using an Array and using push and shift it looks like if you want a traditional Stack behavior.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html

Hope that helps,

Shaun

Comment: wow using an Array worked perfectly.  Thanks a lot!!  Posted the updated code up top.

Comment: @Fran great glad you got it working, Just wanted to clarify as I stated that wrong initially and hate to have misinformation out there on my name.  For a Stack, a first in last out data structure push and pop are the right methods for a traditional Queue first in first out you'd want to use push and shift.  Glad you got it working.